# razor page - global onGet onPost - .net core

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I need to evalutate onGet, onPost globally on each razor page in order to see if a parameter has been sendey within the query string or posted (by jquery.post) in each page.
So at first, i though to add these methods to the _Layout.cshtml but this doesn't seem to be a regular page that can handle these methods.
So i hadded a partial view to the _Layout with OnGet, OnPost but this method are never reached in debug (with a breakpoint)

Note that i've disabled the anti-forgery protection globaly and in this way i'm able to make a jquery.post whitout problems

is there a way to handle  onGet or onPost globally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a BasePageModel with the desired methods:

```cs
public class BasePageModel : PageModel
{
    public void OnGet()
    {
        // ...
    }

    public void OnPost()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Then let all your pages inherit from the base model:

```cs
public class IndexModel : BasePageModel
{
    // OnGet and OnPost are in BasePageModel
}
```